# Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: node.js

Hello im trying to run a program thats made in Node.js
the program is called "LawinServer" and i get this error message when trying to run it (worked before idk why it broke never changed any of the code)
edit: i also have admin perms on my pc lol

```
LawinServer started listening on port 3551
XMPP started listening on port 80
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1363:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1516:7)
    at new WebSocketServer (M:\LawinServer-main\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket-server.js:97:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (M:\LawinServer-main\structure\xmpp.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocketServer instance at:
    at Server.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1407:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}

Node.js v18.2.0

M:\LawinServer-main>pause
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: Try a custom high port, e.g. 8080. Low ports needs to be run as "Administrator"/sudoer

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the tip. I was getting the same error. Changing from port 80 to 8080 did the trick for me